# Video link to PDF doc on a device using Flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to link a video on a device's internal storage (mobile phone IOS or Android) to a pdf (being dynamically created) on the device using Flutter code?

We are building a dynamic pdf report from information being collected on a mobile device. The device will be out of range of a cellular network or WiFi.

It wont be possible use a URL to create a link to the video.

The latest IOS and Android versions wont let this happen. Have tried various ways.